# How to express one function in terms of another function?

Tags: functions

I have two different functions. How can I express $f$ as a function of $g$ in Mathematica?

```
f[t_] = y0 (1 - t/T)^(2/5)
g[t_] = -((2 y0)/(5 T)) (1 - t/T)^(3/5)
```

What Mathematica function could I use? I was thinking about `Solve`; but didn't manage to do it...

Edit: I don't want to define f in terms of g myself; I want Mathematica to find out what f[g] would be based on my input...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[t_] = y0 (1 - t/T)^(2/5);

g[t_] = -((2 y0)/(5 T)) (1 - t/T)^(3/5);
```

To express `f` in terms of `g`

```
(f[t] /. Solve[ig == g[t], y0][[1]] // Simplify) /. ig -> Inactive[g][t]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
(% // Activate) == f[t]

(*  True  *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
expr = (f[t] /. Solve[ig == g[t], t][[1]] // FullSimplify) /. 
  ig -> Inactive[g][t]
```

[image]

```
(expr // Activate) == f[t]

(*  True  *)
```

Assuming, `T > t > 0 && y0 < 0`

```
expr2 = expr // PowerExpand
```

[image]

```
Assuming[T > t > 0 && y0 < 0,
 (expr2 // Activate) == f[t] // Simplify]

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Almost, but it should also be possible to completely eliminate the $t$ and create f[g]. In other words; I want the $t$ in the denominator also to be expressed in terms of $g$

Answer (score 3):

Could define these as equations from which to eliminate `t` and solve for `f`.

```
polys = {y0 (1 - t/T)^(2/5) - f,
   -((2 y0)/(5 T)) (1 - t/T)^(3/5) - g};
Solve[polys == 0, f, t]

During evaluation of In[91]:= Solve::bdomv: Warning: t is not a valid domain specification. Assuming it is a variable to eliminate.

(* Out[92]= {{f -> ((-5)^(2/3) g^(2/3) T^(2/3) y0^(1/3))/2^(
   2/3)}, {f -> (5/2)^(2/3) g^(2/3) T^(2/3) y0^(
    1/3)}, {f -> -(((-1)^(1/3) 5^(2/3) g^(2/3) T^(2/3) y0^(1/3))/2^(
    2/3))}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use `:=` instead of `=` i.e. `f[t_] := y0 (1 - t/T)^(2/5)`
2. you can define f in terms of g like calling any other function `f[t_]:= g[t]`. You didn't express f in terms of g in the question

**Edit** 
To find symbolic value of f[g]

```
In[3]:= f[t_] := y0 (1 - t/T)^(2/5)
g[t_] := -((2 y0)/(5 T)) (1 - t/T)^(3/5)

In[5]:= f[g[t]]

Out[5]= y0 (1 + (2 (1 - t/T)^(3/5) y0)/(5 T^2))^(2/5)
```

**Edit** Well not sure whether I understood the question correctly. What about taking $ f^{-1} $ and applying it on $ g $ ?

```
In[10]:= g[t] /. t -> (InverseFunction[f] /. #1 -> f)

Out[10]= -((2 y0 (1 - ((T y0^2 - T f^2 Sqrt[f/y0])/y0^2 &)/T)^(3/5))/(
 5 T))
```

Comment: I don't want to define f in terms of g myself, because I want Mathematica to find out what f[g] would be based on my input...

Comment: Please mention that in your question

Comment: What if you call `f[g[value]]` ?

Comment: I want the symbolic expression

Comment: `f[g[t]]` will give you the expected result

Comment: Almost; except that the independent variable should be $g$, not $t$

Comment: Oh! now I understand you want to correlate f and g

Comment: Check edited answer